# Programmatically crawl Sharepoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm new to the SharePoint 2013 .Net Client API.  I want to programmatically crawl all of a SharePoint site.  I want to fully extract lists, document, pages, everything!

Ideally I want to start with the root of the website and crawl everything from there.

Can someone give a high-level overview of the basic steps involved?  For example, do I need to create a catalog, or can I simply crawl if I have the admin credentials?

I'm using C#, .Net 4.0, and the Client runtime API (not REST).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that everything in SharePoint lives under a List.  Essentially, I fetch the Lists belonging to a Web and fetch all the ListItems from those.  I ignore Folder and File collections as these are duplicates.

Comment: "fetch the Lists belonging to a Web" How?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the links that were helpful for me :
1.  Crawling with Rest API or PowerShell - [Start a crawl manually via SOAP or REST WebService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095317/start-a-crawl-manually-via-soap-or-rest-webservice) 
2.  Recrawling using code - http://sebastian.expert/force-web-whole-list-library-re-crawled-search-sharepoint-2013-using-api/

Comment: Welcome! It's generally a good idea to at least quote the important part of links when you're using them in an answer. Link-only answers are discouraged, because they become useless if the links are broken. See here for more on writing a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer