# Start a crawl manually via SOAP or REST WebService

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

On a SharePoint 2013 on premise installation, we have configured an incremental crawl, that runs every 15 minutes.

Now we need a possibility to start this crawl manually, too. Is there a WebService we can call to start the crawl manually? Maybe even a possibility to start the crawl on a smaller scope, like only a list or website?

Answer (score 3):

You may just love [Simple HTTP api for Executing PowerShell Scripts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2014/09/29/simple-rest-api-for-executing-powershell-scripts.aspx)

> In cases where you want to simply invoke a PowerShell script remotely,
>   a REST api is a good choice since all modern programming languages
>   make it simple to perform a HTTP GET operation.

and [Simple HTTP api for executing PowerShell scripts](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Simple-REST-api-for-b04489f1) (with source code) which is an out of the box solution of what the above is trying to accomplish. Here are the [Windows PowerShell cmdlets to administer and configure search in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee906563.aspx) for more details.

---

Please also look at [SharePoint Windows PowerShell Remoting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2010/03/07/sharepoint-2010-with-windows-powershell-remoting-step-by-step.aspx) if you are interested on more nitty-gritty remote SharePoint control.

Comment: This is a really interesting solution, though not something I would like to run on our SharePoint. And I'm afraid our definitions what's ootb differ. But since you have already been auto awarded the bounty, congrats.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [powershell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/28/how-to-use-sharepoint-2010-windows-powershell-cmdlets-to-manage-search-crawls.aspx) interface for this purpose.

It is pretty simple when you think about it. 
We can use the `Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource` command to get a `ContentSource` object. 
After we have a reference to this object, we can start, stop, and pause crawls to our heart’s content. 
This class has a few methods that you might be interested in: 
`StartFullCrawl`, `StartIncrementalCrawl`, `StopCrawl`, `PauseCrawl`, and `ResumeCrawl`. 
What each method does should go without explanation.

If it is necessary, you can create a wrapper for powershell call. Your [web service](http://jeffmurr.com/blog/?p=142) will call powershell for this purpose.

Comment: There is. Please see my answer :)